# Add rows and columns to the table on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am  completely new to JavaScript, so, sorry for asking this simple question. The point is that there have been numerous similar questions here and on other platforms. I've tried all solutions provided but neither of them worked in my case. I assume that this is because of my CSS, otherwise I do not know what is the reason. I tried different methods: insertRow, clone etc. neither of them worked.

The point is that my program needs to add row or column to the table on click on the buttons. Right button should add column to the right of the table, bottom button should add row to the bottom of the table.

```js
// append row to the HTML table
function appendRow() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
    row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length), // append table row
    i;
  // insert table cells to the new row
  for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
    createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
  }
};

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), // create DIV element        
    cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
};

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById('my-table'), // table reference
    i;
  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    createCell(tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }
};
```

```css
#canvas {
  align-content: center;
  height: 1000px;
}

#my-table {
  margin: 0 -2px -2px 0;
  border: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid rgb(72, 170, 230);
  display: inline-block;
}

tr {
  background: rgb(72, 170, 230);
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.add {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background: rgb(243, 165, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

#addColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.add:hover {
  background: rgb(246, 192, 82);
}

#addColumnChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#addRow {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}

#addRowChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.del {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background: rgb(178, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

#delColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.del:hover {
  background: rgb(202, 76, 73);
}

#delColumnChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#delRow {
  vertical-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}

#delRowChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test task 1</title>

<body>
  <!-- <div id="delColumn" class="del" onclick="appendColumn">
          <div id="addColumnChild"><b>–</b></div>
        </div>
         <div id="delRow" class="del" onclick="appendRow()">
          <div id="delRowChild"><b>–</b></div>
        </div>-->

  <table id="my-table">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="addColumn" class="add" onclick="appendColumn">
    <div id="addColumnChild"><b>+</b></div>
  </div>
  <div id="addRow" class="add" onclick="appendRow()">
    <div id="addRowChild"><b>+</b></div>
  </div>
```

How to make buttons work and actually add rows and columns?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The way this site works is that you post the code that you are working with and a specific question about the problem you are having. You do not have any JavaScript in your question, which means that you don't have a specific question, you are really looking for a tutorial on how JavaScript works with HTML and that's not what Stack Overflow is for. You should start by learning about JavaScript and the Document Object Model (DOM). Google and YouTube can be very helpful with that.

Comment: @mayua . Are you looking for vanilla `JavaScript` solution? If I provide solution with `jQuery` will be fine?

Comment: Why are you showing us your HTML and CSS, when the issue is with your jQuery? I could see your jQuery in your fiddle and its commented out, so please provide us with the code you have attempted and we may be able to help

Comment: @ScottMarcus Well, they did have their jQuery in the fiddle they linked to, that you removed in your edit....

Comment: @ScottMarcus Please read my comment - I said it was in the *JSFiddle link that you deleted from their question*: https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/gmzqe5kw/8/ Yes, they should include it here too as I said in my comment, but please add back the link they provided.

Comment: @ScottMarcus "*the commented code appears again (uncommented) at the bottom*"... not in the version I'm looking at?  https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/gmzqe5kw/8/ "*And, of course the HTML and CSS should be provided*"... it is also in the jsFiddle.......? Its not perfect, but at least its an attempt and something they can work from.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see you included the jQuery directly in the question - please ***add back the link to their fiddle*** - thats clearly what the OP is most comfortable working in and it is *their* question.

Comment: @FluffyKitten There is no reason to link out to an external site for code that can and should be included right here in the question. 3rd party links for code are discouraged at Stack Overflow as those links can become stale/dead over time. The OP is new to SO and they should become familiar with how this site works.

Comment: @ScottMarcus 3rd party links are perfectly acceptable in Stack Overflow, as long as they are accompanied with the code or relevant section in the question/answer - which the OP attempted to do (just not fully). As I said, this is the OP's question and it is obviously their preference to work in JSFiddle (especially seeing as they have a JSFiddle account) and they haven't done anything against the terms of the site by including it along with the code.

Comment: @Shiladitya jQuery should be fine, but simple JS is the best option. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the suggestions. I've included the link to jsfiddle since 95% of all similar to mine questions here had links to this platform. Moreover I thought that it will be easier for other members to see the result and to experiment on the solution. I have not included my own JS code because, as I mentioned I used tons of options and neither of them worked, so I decided that I can simply ask for the suggestions how it can work)

Comment: @FluffyKitten Thank you for the support. I can not add code which I'd like to use here (because it is too long) so I've simply copied it here: https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/gmzqe5kw/9/ in the JS window. This solution seems great to me because it loops over the rows and analyses how many columns/cells are there and adds a particular number of cells, same with columns.

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've also added the JS code in my initial post.

Comment: The fact that a large majority of new people to Stack Overflow post their code on 3rd party sites is not confirmation that this is the correct thing to do. In fact, more often than not, when that occurs, someone will usually comment (just as I did to you) that this is not the right approach for Stack Overflow. As I stated before, it is not easier for us to help you when we have to leave the page with your question and go to another site, when you can post a working code snippet right here in your question (as I have done by editing your question). Also, 3rd party links can become dead over...

Comment: ...time, which make your original question here meaningless if the code isn't accessible. Please try to follow the etiquette here or you may find that many of your questions get down voted and/or go unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution (using `jQuery`) https://jsfiddle.net/gmzqe5kw/11/

```js
$('#addColumnChild').click(function(){
   $('#my-table tr').each(function(){
      $(this).append(`<td></td>`);
   });
});

$('#addRowChild').click(function(){
   $('#my-table tbody').append(`<tr>${$('#default-row').html()}</tr>`);
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  align-content: center;
  height: 1000px;
}

#my-table {
  margin: 0 -2px -2px 0;
  border: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid rgb(72, 170, 230);
  display: inline-block;
}

tr {
  background: rgb(72, 170, 230);
}

td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.add {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background: rgb(243, 165, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

#addColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.add:hover {
  background: rgb(246, 192, 82);
}

#addColumnChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#addRow {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}

#addRowChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.del {
  height: 52px;
  width: 52px;
  background: rgb(178, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  transition-property: background;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
}

#delColumn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
}

.del:hover {
  background: rgb(202, 76, 73);
}

#delColumnChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}

#delRow {
  vertical-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
}

#delRowChild {
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
  <tr id="default-row">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="addColumn" class="add">
  <div id="addColumnChild"><b>+</b></div>
</div>
<div id="addRow" class="add">
  <div id="addRowChild"><b>+</b></div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: BUT! Do you have any idea why it does not work if I copy the code into another fiddle?

Comment: For example here: the same code but it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/mozghovyi/cLmamo80/ :(

Comment: You are missing `jQuery` library, please add `jQuery` in your project as well as in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Add this to the head section of your appilication `<script type="javascript/text" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: Thank you! I've added JQuery and it works now! I've accepted the answer and tried to up vote but it says that I can not up vote because my reputation is not high enough. Can I ask some moderator to do this for me? Sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: I'll come back here when I have enough reputation and will vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery events and selectors:

As an example, to add a row, use general solution is of this form:

```
$(".some_selector").click(function () {
    $("table.your_class").append("<tr> <td>col1</td> <td>col2</td> </tr>");
});
```

To add columns use:

similarly to add columns:

```
$(".some_selector").click(function () {
    // Loop over the rows of the table and append the td tag
    $("table.your_class tr").append("<td>col1</td>");
});
```

Comment: Kamran, thank you for the suggestion, I do not think it will work here. I can not use a fixed html inside append because I need to add columns and rows and your suggestion will add the same quantity of cells in the row. Or I am mistaken?

Comment: You should look at a tutorial such as https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-append-and-remove-table-row-dynamically